# Check validation in Laravel in request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 6.

I have this code (UserRequest):

```
return $this->isIndividualClient()
            ? [
                'info.first_name' => ['required', 'max:191', 'alpha_dash'],
                'info.last_name' => ['required', 'max:191', 'alpha_dash'],
                'info.birth_place' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                'info.birth_date' => ['required'],
                'email' => ['required', 'email', Rule::unique('clients')->ignore($this->route("client"))->whereNull('deleted_at')],
                'info.phone_nr' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                'info.address' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                'info.city' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                'info.postal_code' => ['required', 'max:191']
            ]
            : [
                'company_info.name' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                'email' => ['required', 'email', Rule::unique('clients')->ignore($this->route("client"))->whereNull('deleted_at')],
                'company_info.nip' => ['required', new Nip],
                'company_info.phone_nr' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                'company_info.address' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                'company_info.city' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                'company_info.postal_code' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                'address.company_name' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                'address.nip' => ['required', new Nip],
                'address.address' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                'address.city' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                'address.postal_code' => ['required', 'max:191'],
            ];
```

I need add if statement in my validation:

```
if($request->input('need_invoice'){
'address.company_name' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                    'address.nip' => ['required', new Nip],
                    'address.address' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                    'address.city' => ['required', 'max:191'],
                    'address.postal_code' => ['required', 'max:191'],
}
```

If user / post individual user and need't invoice - this part of validation I need turn off.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just merge your array before returning it:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = $this->isIndividualClient()
        ? [
            'info.first_name' => ['required', 'max:191', 'alpha_dash'],
            'info.last_name' => ['required', 'max:191', 'alpha_dash'],
            'info.birth_place' => ['required', 'max:191'],
            'info.birth_date' => ['required'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', Rule::unique('clients')
                ->ignore($this->route("client"))
                ->whereNull('deleted_at')],
            'info.phone_nr' => ['required', 'max:191'],
            'info.address' => ['required', 'max:191'],
            'info.city' => ['required', 'max:191'],
            'info.postal_code' => ['required', 'max:191']
        ]
        : [
            'company_info.name' => ['required', 'max:191'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', Rule::unique('clients')
                ->ignore($this->route("client"))
                ->whereNull('deleted_at')],
            'company_info.nip' => ['required', new Nip],
            'company_info.phone_nr' => ['required', 'max:191'],
            'company_info.address' => ['required', 'max:191'],
            'company_info.city' => ['required', 'max:191'],
            'company_info.postal_code' => ['required', 'max:191'],
        ];

    if ($this->input('need_invoice')) {
        $rules = array_merge($rules, [
            'address.company_name' => ['required', 'max:191'],
            'address.nip' => ['required', new Nip],
            'address.address' => ['required', 'max:191'],
            'address.city' => ['required', 'max:191'],
            'address.postal_code' => ['required', 'max:191'],
        ]);
    }

    return $rules;
}
```